# Downloading modules from PowerShell Gallery with PowerShell v2

Tags: powershell-2.0

PowerShell v2 has no access to the PowerShell Gallery. Backports of the `Install-Module` of module `PowerShellGet` only exist for v3 and v4. The PowerShell Gallery does not offer/allow manual download.

I looked for the code of module `PowerShellGet` to find out how the download works (to re-implement or run manually), but could not find its code.

How can I download modules for/with PowerShell v2? I hope there is a basic schema I could follow.

Comment: The basic schema of "upgrade to PowerShell v3"?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers not on XP. But let's not go there ;-)